# C++- error C2144 syntax error : 'int' should be preceded by ';'

Tags: c++

I'm trying to compile this C++ code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>   
#include <string.h>
#include "general_configuration.h"
#include "helper_functions.h"

#define LINE_LEN 80

// file_with_as_ext returns 1 if the input has .as extension
int file_with_as_ext(char* input)
{
  char* dot_value = strchr(input, '.');
  if (dot_value == NULL)
    return 0;
  else
  {
    if (strcmp(dot_value,".as") == 0)
      return 1;
  }
}
```

But I'm getting the error `"C2144: syntax error : 'int' should be preceded by ';'"`

And I can't understand why, because `#define` doesn't need `';'` at the end.

Comment: Sounds like you have something in `helper_functions.h` that should end with a semicolon but doesn't.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily have to be because of define, but could also be because of something in the header file, like a struct, oder a class, you didn't close properly. Please check those custom headers too and post their content, if you can't find it there.

Comment: When you have fixed the header, then *replace the `#define`* with a C++ constant definition, replace the use of raw `char` arrays with `std::string`, and sprikle a generous helping of `const` all over the place.

Comment: You are right the problem was with a missing ';

Comment: you are right the problem was with a missing ';' on the header file. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, the code you have posted begins with a stray backtick.  If that's really in your code, you should remove it.

Second, the compiler would be happier, and emit fewer warnings, if you ended your function with the line

```
return 0; // unreachable
```

This is good C++ style and is recommended.  (In your case, the line may actually be *reachable,* in which case the line is not only good style but necessary for correct operation.  Check this.)

Otherwise, your code looks all right except for some small objections one could raise regarding the outdated, C-style use of `#define` and regarding one or two other minor points of style.  Regarding the `#define`, it is not C++ source code as such but is a *preprocessor directive.*  It is actually handled by a different program than the compiler, and is removed and replaced by proper C++ code before the compiler sees it.  The preprocessor is not interested in semicolons.  This is why the `#define` line does not end in a semicolon.  Neither do other lines that begin `#` usually end in semicolons.

As @JoachimIsaksson has noted, a needed semicolon may be missing from the end of the file `general_configuration.h` or the file `helper_function.h`.  You should check the last line in each file.

Comment: you are right, a ; was missing on the h file. Thanks

Answer (score 14):

I encounted this issue. I wrote a header file, but I forgot to add ";" at the tail of a function declaration. So, there is a error in my c file which is include this header file.
I add comment here, and hope it will be useful for someone.

Answer (score 0):

> And I can't understand why, #define doesn't need ';' at the end.

Because #define is not a statement, but a *preprocessor directive*, and the preprocessor is line-oriented when it comes to separating directives. For example, you cannot put two #defines on the same line.